# How omit readonly fields and fields that can't get focus in Excel type navigation?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table containing rows and cells. What I would like to do is omit fields that are readonly or fields like labels who can't get focus. Purpose is to move to next input cell which is editable using arrow keys.

Code is like following:

Traverse the cursor through text box with navigation keys omitting readonly fields or labels.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which==39)
   $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();     
  else if(e.which==37)
   $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus();
  else if(e.which==40)
   $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').focus();
  else if(e.which==38)
   $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').focus();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the editable cells and let the selector do the work.

```
 $(this).closest('td').next('.editable')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already not selecting labels by specifying `'input'`

Only select non-readonly inputs like this:

```
.find('input:not([readonly])')
```

Comment: I tested both this and code above but they didn't skip the readonly column, just stayed in first column which wasn't readonly. In table like this 
<table> How to skip readonly column to next editable?
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input readonly="true" type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
   <td><input readonly="true" type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
 </tr>
</table>